# query on iOS app deployment methods

Tags: ios

Googling this topic I get a sense there are three ways apple allows to distribute the app to end user. However it's still quite vague how exactly each one of these methods actually work and differ.

1. **Ad Hoc Distribution** - how does this really work. does this method not require the app to be submitted on app store ? If Yes , then where will the user download the app from  and how the installation procedure works.
2. **In-House Distribution** - how does this work ? some text i came across suggests we can host the app on a private enterprise server and allow users install from there. If this is true apple would have no way to regulate the app.. not so clear.
3. **App Store deployment** -  this one i understand how it works as a consumer of some apps i have purchased from app store. In this case the app will have to be submitted to app store first and then available for any number of users to install.

The other question I had on the same context is to be able to deploy the app via one of the ways what type of dev **license** is required to be procured from apple ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad Hoc Distribution - This is most commonly used for sending the applications to beta testers, you register their UDID in your Developer Portal and then send them the app bundle and a provisioning profile. They drag these into iTunes and can install the application.

In-House Distribution - If I recall correctly this is only available if you have Enterprise license, you can deploy this app to all devices associated with that account (so all of your companies phone for example)

App Store Distribution - This is when your app ends up in the App Store, you submit it to Apple after code signing it, then they review and it gets accepted.

Hopefully that clears things up a bit for you.

For distribution methods 1 & 3 you must have paid the $99 developer fee, number 2 you must have paid $299 (I think that's the right price) for the enterprise developer license.

Comment: thanks for a quick response. For the Ad Hoc method do i need to craete diff provisioning for each tester ? Also the other question i had was for In-House distribution does the app become visible on app store - i guess not ? is there any link that can explain the hosting procedure for inhouse a bit more then pls share. appreaciate your time.

Comment: You create 1 provisioning profile that works for all devices you choose to add to it when creating the profile. With In-House distribution it does not appear in the store. This PDF details all the in-house distribution methods http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iPhone_Business.pdf

Comment: If I want to deploy to submit it to app store, is there a guide?

Answer (score 2):

For the Ad-Hoc thing: You can add up to 100 devices per year to your dev portal. Those 100 devices are then able to install specially signed Apps from you.

To add a device to your portal you need it's UDID. To distribute an App via Ad-Hoc you need to create a special Ad-Hoc distribution profile for the App, sign it with this profile and then send the compiled .app file bundled with the profile to your users. They will then be able to install the app via iTunes, just like they've downloaded it from the App Store.

Note: Removing a previously added device from the list does not increase the device count by.

That's pretty much it, am not familiar with in-house distribution.

Comment: "Removing a previously added device from the list does not increase the device count " - means once a device is added it eats one beta tester slot for ever and removing this uuis would not empty that slot ?

Comment: It only "blocks" it until your membership expires. If you renew it (once a year), the slot will be free again.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's definition of "in-house" distribution basically means: buy an enterprise developer account.

http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/apps/in-house/resources.html